# could not find executable file

Tags: ros, kinect, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I am trying to use Voxelized Shape and Color Histograms (VOSCH) in order to recognize an object,  I follow this link http://wiki.ros.org/vosch ,but when I run :

> rosrun vosch example_vosch `rospack find vosch`/data/sample_cone_green.pcd

I got the Error that

> Couldn't find executable named example_vosch below   /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/mapping/vosch

can anyone help me to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155991/could-not-find-executable-file/) by [ghazaleh](https://answers.ros.org/users/11236/ghazaleh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that you did not compile it after downloading the package.

Please check that all dependencies are installed and it compiles without errors. Then it should find the executable.

You can also try

`rosmake --pre-clean <package_name>`

to remove the previous builds and compile it right now in your system.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0